# Is decrease in quality inevitable?

Tags: discussion, quality

I've been a member of SO for [little over a month](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) and lately I've noticing that people are asking questions that are:

- Easily searchable;
- Copy and pasted homework questions;
- Verifiable by testing it themselves;
- OP has a sense of entitlement
- ...

And of course are also poorly formatted, poorly worded questions that show the OP has put minimal effort into the question. I am not sure if I just haven't been here long enough, or it's just me being pessimistic, but am I the only one noticing a trend of decreasing quality in posts?

*(Let's not forget members who think they know more about programming than they actually do, leading to answers with poor quality as well.)*

So, as the community grows larger, is it inevitable that we will become a programming version of Yahoo Answers? If such a trend exists, how can we reverse it?

Comment: You aren't the only one. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system ♪

Comment: Don't bury it yet.  It's the dog days of summer, Europe is on vacation.  End-of-term summer school projects are due.